# Get transparent background by using mask, I get white background

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, image-processing, mask

```
def combined_display(image, matte):
  # calculate display resolution
  w, h = image.width, image.height
  rw, rh = 800, int(h * 800 / (3 * w))
  
  # obtain predicted foreground
  image = np.asarray(image)
  if len(image.shape) == 2:
    image = image[:, :, None]
  if image.shape[2] == 1:
    image = np.repeat(image, 3, axis=2)
  elif image.shape[2] == 4:
    image = image[:, :, 0:3]
  matte = np.repeat(np.asarray(matte)[:, :, None], 3, axis=2) / 255
  foreground = image * matte + np.full(image.shape, 255) * (1 - matte)
  
  foreground =  Image.fromarray(np.uint8(foreground))
  foreground.save("imag.png", format="png")
  return foreground
```

I'm trying to get transparent background like removebg, I don't want white background. Please help me with removing background and get transparent background.

[image]

Comment: To get transparency you'll need 4 channels per pixel, not 3.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a 3-channel image and a 1-channel mask. Then you can stack them together into a 4-channel image where the last channel is responsible for transparency.

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('image.png')
mask = Image.open('mask.png').convert('L')

image_with_transparency = np.dstack((image, mask))

Image.fromarray(image_with_transparency).save('image_trs.png')
```

The result:

[image]